# Evolution of dinosaurs

Tags: evolution, herpetology, dinosaurs

What did dinosaurs evolve from? Was it the reptiles that evolved from amphibians? I have been researching this but am very confused with who their direct predecessor was. Amphibians evolved from fish...reptiles from  amphibians...dinosaurs from reptiles (?)...and birds from dinosaurs. That is my understanding, but it could be wrong. How are dinosaurs related to reptiles? And if they did evolve from reptiles, which kind of reptiles (such as lizards, crocodiles, or turtles for example)?

Comment: Related: [If dinosaurs could have feathers, would they still be reptiles?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/35370/if-dinosaurs-could-have-feathers-would-they-still-be-reptiles)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Source of information**

See the post [The best free and most up to date phylogenetic tree on the internet?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/52142/the-best-free-and-most-up-to-date-phylogenetic-tree-on-the-internet) for info about how to find such information.

Generally speaking, you might be interested in an intro to phylogenetics such as the one provided in [this answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/52700/why-do-the-ancestors-of-birds-still-exist/52729#52729) for example.

**Where are dinosaurs in the tree of life?**

Dinosaurs fall within the *Reptiliomorpha* clade. Please note that *Reptiliomorpha* does not quite correspond to what we today call reptiles. Please see the post [If dinosaurs could have feathers, would they still be reptiles?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/35370/if-dinosaurs-could-have-feathers-would-they-still-be-reptiles)

*Reptiliomorpha* is the sister clade to *Amphibia* (from [here](http://tolweb.org/Terrestrial_Vertebrates/14952)) which contain all living amphibians.

[image]

If you look within the *Amniota*, you will find all of the following

[image]

Here, you see that turtles and mammals are an off-shoot of *Diapsida*. So dinosaurs are not mammals and there are not closely related to turtles. Now if you click on *Diapsida* you will find ...

[image]

the *Archosauromorpha* which contains all crocodiles, birds and dinosaurs. You can keep going to find *Therapoda* which contains many dinosaurs and birds. You can keep going like this for yourself and discover the entire tree of life!

[image]

**Reacting to your sentences**

> What did dinosaurs evolve from?

When asking this question, please do not forget that no species evolved from an extant species. If this is unclear to you, you should have a look at [this post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20177/extinction-of-species).

> Was it the reptiles that evolved from amphibians?

Well... the term reptile is a mess because it does not represent a monophyletic group (see [this post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/35370/if-dinosaurs-could-have-feathers-would-they-still-be-reptiles)). If you do not understand the term monophyletic, then you should have a look at [this answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/52700/why-do-the-ancestors-of-birds-still-exist/52729#52729).

> Amphibians evolved from fish...

Well... sure. However, fish is also not monophyletic so it is misleading. Also, I am afraid when you say "Amphibians evolved from fish" that you are thinking of modern extant fish which would be wrong.

> reptiles from amphibians...

Nope, this is wrong. Reptiles and amphibians are sister(-ish) clades.

> dinosaurs from reptiles (?)...

This is more or less true although again, do not think of modern reptiles and also, reptiles is a mess because it is not a monophyletic group. But Dinosaurs are Reptilia

> and birds from dinosaurs.

Yes, this is pretty much true.

Note generally though that it is misleading to say "birds evolved from dinosaurs", "humans evolved from apes" and "mammals evolved from vertebrates". It is more correct to say "birds are dinosaurs", "humans are apes" and "mammals are vertebrates". I would be even better to use the latin names to avoid confusion with misuse of these words in the popular culture.

Comment: Nice answer!...

Comment: When you say no species has evolved from an extant species, why is that? Wouldn't the Galapagos finches have evolved from an extant species of finch in South America? Meaning that they did indeed evolve from an extant species? (I did read the linked post, but I am still a bit confused)

Comment: @Hawkeye The sentence you are referring to is followed by "If this is unclear to you, you should have a look at [this post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20177/extinction-of-species)".  [This post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/52700/why-do-the-ancestors-of-birds-still-exist/52729#52729) would also give you a good explanation.

Comment: @Remi.b If I am understanding the linked posts correctly: No species has evolved from an extant species because the species has also been evolving and is now different, no matter how slight. Am I thinking of that correctly?

Comment: @Hawkeye Yep pretty much! Good job!

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer! Just a few questions to make sure I properly understand it. At some point in time, Reptilia divided into Anapsida and Romeriida. Turtles are included under Anapsida while dinosaurs fall under Romeriida. So they are related, but one is not the ancestor to another. Is this correct? Dinosaurs and turtles are more related than dinosaurs and members of Amphibia but less related than dinosaurs and birds. Your anwser cleared a lot of things up, but I just want to make sure I grasp the concept

Comment: You got it! It feels good when the OP fully gets it! Good job @Vanessa! Note that tolweb.org (the reference I used) is a little bit updated. OneZoom.org is a bit better (see [the tetrapods here](http://www.onezoom.org/life/@Sarcopterygii=458402?vis=spiral#x-275,y-46,w1.7188)). There are a few changes what you just expressed remains true.

Answer (score 2):

If you check [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution_of_dinosaurs) you can find that dinosaurs evolved in the clade of [Archosaurs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archosaur). Crocodiles and birds are still living representatives of the Archosaurs. The most recent common ancestor of birds and crocodiles, was also the ancestor of the dinosaurs and was a reptile.